# How to schedule an auto refresh of excel imported from SharePoint?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, refresh, schedule

I have created an excel file using the "export to excel" feature in SharePoint. Every time I open the excel I have to hit "Refresh all" button to bring the new data to my excel sheet. Is there any way I can schedule that refresh? In the connection -> properties -> usage next to "Refresh all" button  "Refresh every" option is greyed out. Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you extract the file from sharepoint and have it  on a pvot table?

Comment: Nope, I am not creating any pivot table.

Comment: apologies, my comment was cut out, what i was trying to ask was, if  you  extract your excel file from sharepoint, is there any option that can create a pvot table? if yes, then we can use that to trigger the refresh all button